# how to create media link entity in odata4j

Tags: odata, odata4j

how to create media link entity in odata4j.

like following:

```
{
    "__mediaresource": {
        "edit_media": "http://server/uploads/Thumbnail546.jpg",
        "media_src": "http://server/Thumbnail546.jpeg",
        "content-type": "img/jpeg",
        "media_etag": "####"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MLEs are not yet supported by odata4j. The project [roadmap](https://code.google.com/p/odata4j/wiki/Roadmap) states it as one of the goals for version 1.0 which will be even after the next release (0.8).